# Invalid tag for push notifications in Windows Azure

Tags: push-notification, windows-phone-8.1, azure-mobile-services

I am building a Windows Phone 8.1 application and want to add push notifications from Windows Azure. I am creating the channel by using CreatePushNotificationChannelForApplicationAsync, after which I take the resulting URI and store it in the Azure database. When trying to send a push notification by using push.wns.sendToastText01, I get the following error in the Azure logs:

> Error in script '/table/Message.insert.js'. Error: 400 - An invalid tag 'https://db3.notify.windows.com/?token=AwYAAAC3tTi3W5ItZ0hWdZ3FLmELt%2flHcwpsM...' was supplied. Valid tag characters are alphanumeric, _, @, -, ., : and #.

I noticed that the channel URI contains the '%' which does not appear among the valid characters, yet that is the URI that gets generated in the client application. Am I using a wrong method for sending push notifications or is there something else I am missing?

Edit: I am using Node.js for backend in Azure.

```
request.execute({
                          success: function() {
                                push.wns.sendToastText01(channelUri, {
                                    text1: "Google Plus Friend Tracker",
                                    text2: item.content,
                                    param: '/ChatPage.xaml?friendGoogleId=' + item.author_id
                                })
                            }
                        });
```

Comment: Can you be more specific? Are you using JS Backend? Can you provide some code snippets?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the [wns object documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/jj860484.aspx), the first parameter would be the tags that you are sending to. Since you're providing a channel in the code above, you are getting the error specified.

The backend does not need to provide the channel URI, as this was associated with the Notification Hub via the client-side registration action. If you are broadcasting the message, you would just provide null as the tag value. Otherwise, you can use the tags that were specified when you registered the channel URI.

For more about the process, see the ["Get started with push"](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-services-javascript-backend-windows-universal-dotnet-get-started-push/) tutorial. There is also an example of using a tag (user ID) in the ["Send push notifications to authenticated users"](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-services-javascript-backend-windows-store-dotnet-push-notifications-app-users/) tutorial. For more on tags in general, the [Notification Hubs breaking news tutorial](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/notification-hubs-windows-store-dotnet-send-breaking-news/) is also good.